# Triangle inequalities, with angle bisector

Tags: geometry, triangles

I came across this question while I was taking one of the pratice Mu Alpha Theta tests for my school and I wasn't sure how to solve it. It reads:
In $\Delta USA $, $\angle S$ is bisected by $\overrightarrow {SY}$, with $Y$ on side $\overline {UA}$. If all sides have integer values, $ \overline{US}=18 $ and $ \overline{UY} = 12 $; find the smallest possible perimeter of $\Delta USA$.

The answer key with the solutions skipped to the part with the triangle inequalities, so that is why I am not sure what to do. I think there is some ratio when it comes to splitting a triangle with an angle bisector but I am not sure what it is. My question is how would I solve this question, and for future reference what is that ratio for an angle bisector in a triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The relevant theorem about angle bisectors (adapted to your labels) is
$$\frac{AY}{YU}=\frac{SA}{SU}.$$

Comment: Oh then you could, find the lengths, and then using The Triangle Inequality find what the shortest possible lengths could be. Thank You!